# (Cloud Foundry, Node.js) 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

After a few days, sometimes my previously running application will flake out with this error and no longer load. I have searched, but have not found the cause. I have a hunch that it may be because I'm giving my Node.js app only 256MB memory, but cannot confirm. Any recommendations?

Comment: We need more information. What do your logs say? Based on a response from a similar question, please run the following command: cf logs <appname> --recent

Comment: A 502 message often means that the application crashed and the logs can help reveal why.

Comment: This error is saying that an incoming request was delivered to your application, but no response was received within the timeout (I think 60s, but it likely depend on your provider).  An incoming request will go through a layer of proxies, to the GoRouter and then to your application.  The GoRouter waits for the response and if one does not come fast enough, will generate this error.  In addition to checking logs, I would check that your application is not hung and not using all its CPU.  Something is causing the app to be running, but not responding.

Comment: The logs actually don't show any errors. I noticed this is only happening for UIs where Node Express serves static the UI. It shows the HTML/CSS all messed up/not loaded, but I don't see anything wrong when I check the network tab. It seems to happen rather randomly, and is "fixed" by just cf push again.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, that was related to `PORT` using, I had given Hardcoded value in `PORT` that was an issue, then I used `AppEnv` of `cfenv` module and used `AppEnv().port`.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

A 502 error can mean a variety of things, but without any logs, it is difficult to say for sure.

I agree that there is a good chance that your app is potentially running out of memory given the symptoms (or there could be a code bug which is causing some kind of unresponsive behavior).

There could be internal Cloud Foundry GoRouter / networking problems, but to debug those, you would probably need to CF SSH into a running container and trace packets. When you push the app again, you will most-likely get deployed to different machines, so many times network issues will resolve when that happens. (Given the seemingly consistent behavior of your error, I think this is unlikely.)

Comment: I can follow up with you if you have some more questions/data and update the answer.